# One Frame To Another Frame in Java.Net Beans

Tags: java

I Am Creating an App in First Frame I've Create a Continue Button.
But I Want To Know That How 2nd Frame Will Appear After Clicking Continue..
When I Click Double Click on BUTTON. This Code Will Appear.

```
**@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setText("Generation's School");
    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("a Happy Place To Learn. . .");
    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Adobe Caslon Pro", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel3.setText("Parents / Teacher Appointment");
    jButton1.setText("Continue");
    jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 397, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(141, 141, 141))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 386, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGap(21, 21, 21))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(16, 16, 16)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:



}                                        
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}                                     
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Form1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });**
```

Now What i have To Do Further Please Guide Me.

Thanks.

Comment: *"Please Guide Me"* - Get out of the form editor, seriously.  You will learn more faster and appreciate when a form editor is useful and how to use it.  Have a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for some more ideas and avoid using multiple windows where possible

Comment: Actually I am Learning JAVA in NET BEANS Thats Why I am Doing it on NetBeans.

Comment: That's nice, but seriously, the form editor is going to encourage you to learn bad practices.  Still, a `CardLayout` would be a preferred mechanism over a another frame

Comment: But I Dont Know How To Use Card Layout Can You Please Guide Me Remotely?

Comment: I am Doing This But Its Show Error.

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Form2 frm2.new Form2();
        frm2.setSize(425,322);
        frm.setVisible(True);

Comment: Don't use a `MouseListener` within buttons, use a `ActionListener`, see [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)